# Open Excel File in write mode using Button WPF

Tags: c#, excel

Hello as the title says I'm trying to make a button that opens a excel file in write mode in wpf but i can't make it work its always opening the excel file in read only.

```
        private void btnFileOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        fileExcel = "C:\\Random\\1.xlsx";
        Excel.Application xlApp;
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook;
        xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        //open workbook
        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fileExcel, 0, true, 5, "", "", true, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false, false, 0, true, 1, 0);
        xlApp.Visible = true; 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call the`Open` method with third parameter `(ReadOnly) = false`.

See MSDN [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=excel-pia#Microsoft_Office_Interop_Excel_Workbooks_Open_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_System_Object_):

**ReadOnly**

> Optional Object. True to open the workbook in read-only mode.
>
> False to open the workbook in r&w mode